# Mule: HTTP connector failing due to string payload

Tags: mule

I am trying to make a rest call via the http connector. I build the payload as a string, then when I am trying to send it to the client, I am getting the following error:

> org.mule.api.MessagingException: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: String

the string looks as follows:

```
{
    "firstName": "Nathan4",
    "lastName": "Tregillus",
    "email": "ntregillus@solarcity.com"
}
```

at this time I am just confused. is there only one type of body I can send?

Comment: Were you able to set the Content-Type as application/json prior to making a rest call?

Comment: Show your config and show the full exception. It's impossible to help with such partial information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not show your config I would suspect that there is some problems your mule instance and the service you're consuming, or the remote endpoint is having trouble generating the response. So you can check your config:

- Methods (POST or Get)
- Path
- config-ref
- name

Comment: I found my problem, I was setting the message properties, then setting the payload. when I changed the order it all worked